# Python C++ API - how to access/set class atributes from Python?

Tags: python-c-api

I have created getsetters for a public variable **number_bananas** I have in my **Box** class. 
**number_bananas** is public because the box is unlocked, anyone can eat bananas or put more in the box.

Here is my PyBox type:

```
typedef struct 
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    Box *bx;
} PyBox;
```

In my Box class I have defined:

```
class Box {
   public:
      Box(double l, double b, double h);
      int number_bananas;
   ...

Box::Box(double l, double b, double h)
{
        number_bananas = 11;
        length         = l;
        breadth        = b;
        height         = h;       
}
```

and here are the get/setters I have defined:

```
static PyObject *pyBox_getBananas(PyBox *self, void *closure)
{
    Py_INCREF(self->bx->number_bananas);
    return self->bx->number_bananas;
}

static int pyBox_setBananas(PyBox *self, PyObject *value, void *closure)
{
    if (value == NULL) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "You're trying to put something that is not a banana!!");
        return -1;
    }

    Py_DECREF(self->bx->number_bananas);
    Py_INCREF(value);
    self->bx->number_bananas = value;

    return 0;
}

static PyGetSetDef pyBox_getseters[] = {
    {"number_bananas", (getter)pyBox_getBananas, (setter)pyBox_setBananas, "number of bananas", NULL},
    {NULL}
};
```

The constructor I have used to instantiate the Box class is defined by:

```
static int pyBox_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    static char* nams[] = {"length","breadth","height", NULL};
    int l, b, h;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "iii", nams, &l, &b, &h))
        return -1;

    ((PyBox *)self)->bx = &(Box::Box(l,b,h));

    return 0;
}

static PyObject *pyBox_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyBox *self;
    self = (PyBox *) type->tp_alloc(type, 0);

    return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

The module compiles successfully. However, I cannot find how to access the property **number_bananas** from Python.

The following results in Fatal error (segfault):

```
import adventureIsland

bo = adventureIsland.box(1,1,1)

print(bo.number_bananas)
```

So... my question is how do I access/set the **number_bananas** from Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self->bx->number_bananas` is not a `PyObject*` so can't be increfed or decrefed. Instead you want to be converting it to/from a `PyObject*`. In Python3 you do this with [various `PyLong_*` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html).

Some untested code would be:

```
static PyObject *pyBox_getBananas(PyBox *self, void *closure)
{
    return PyLong_FromLong(self->bx->number_bananas);
}

static int pyBox_setBananas(PyBox *self, PyObject *value, void *closure)
{
    if (value == NULL) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "You're trying delete the attribute!!");
        return -1;
    }

    int valuei = PyLong_AsLong(value);
    if (valuei==-1 and PyErr_Occurrred()) {
        return -1;
    }

    self->bx->number_bananas = valuei;

    return 0;
}
```

Potentially there might be problems with too large numbers if `int` (`number_of_bananas`) and `long` (the result of `PyLong_AsLong`) aren't the same size, which it might be worth you trying to identify and raise an exception.

---

You were having further issues due to a constructor problem:

```
((PyBox *)self)->bx = &(Box::Box(l,b,h));
```

This sets `bx` to point to a temporary `Box` that stops existing almost as soon as it is created. What you should be doing is allocating a `Box` on the heap using the `new` operator. (What's happening now is that the memory you're pointing to is being reused in other functions so the "value" is changing in confusing ways).

```
((PyBox *)self)->bx = new Box::Box(l,b,h);
```

You should then make sure you `delete` this in the destructor (to avoid a memory leak).

Comment: Thanks! However, when I run print(bo.number_bananas) i get a random negative number. In my Box::box() i have defined number_bananas = 11; Why is it not getting the value of  number_bananas right?

Comment: The big bit of code you haven't included is the constructor for `PyBox`. At a guess you haven't set `PyBox->bx` to point at a valid `Box` (or you've possibly set it to point at a local variable or something like that).

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question with the constructor. It is weird because i cannot access the attirbutes of PyBox, but I can exercise its methods.

Comment: I will create a new question for this, as my question is getting a bit messy!

Comment: @PintoDoido See edit - it's a constructor problem (as I guessed). It's easily fixed.